# set imageview onclick of current page in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, imageview, onclicklistener, android-pageradapter

Hello guys I am using viewpager in my application,
On a page there is one imageview. on this image view i set onclick listener.
When i am going to click on this imageview and change image on it, image of next page is get changed and current page image is remain unchanged.
How to change only image of current Page not next.

Here is my code.

```
public class KahawateViewPager extends android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter{
Context kahawateViewPagerContext;

ImageView kahawateLikeUnlike_ImageView;
TextView kahawateIdiom_TextView;
TextView kahawateIdiomCountry_TextView;

LayoutInflater kahawateViewPagerLayout_LayoutInflater;

public KahawateViewPager(Context context)
{
    this.kahawateViewPagerContext = context;

}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    //set page count only for testing
    return 10;
}

 @Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position)
{
    kahawateViewPagerLayout_LayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) kahawateViewPagerContext.getSystemService(kahawateViewPagerContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final View itemView = kahawateViewPagerLayout_LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.kahawate_viewpager_layout, container, false);

    kahawateIdiom_TextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_idieom);

    kahawateIdiomCountry_TextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_ideiomCountry);

    kahawateLikeUnlike_ImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_favourite);

    setKahawateData(position);

    kahawateLikeUnlike_ImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Toast.makeText(kahawateViewPagerContext,"Current Position"+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(kahawateLikeUnlike_ImageView.getTag().equals("like"))
            {

                kahawateLikeUnlike_ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.unlike);
                kahawateLikeUnlike_ImageView.setTag("unlike");
            } else
            {
                kahawateLikeUnlike_ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);
                kahawateLikeUnlike_ImageView.setTag("like");
            }
        }
        //}
    });

            ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);


    return itemView;
}


@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object)
{
    return view == ((LinearLayout)object);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((LinearLayout) object);

}
void setKahawateData(int ID)
{       
        //setdefault image only for testing 
        kahawateLikeUnlike_ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);
        kahawateLikeUnlike_ImageView.setTag("like");

}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

}

here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:background="#f4e9cd">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView_favourite"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/unlike"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_idieom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Big Data"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_ideiomCountry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Small Data"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

here is screen the star image i want to set/reset
[image]

Here toast current position 0 is showing but when i click the position 1 page imageview get set. and if I click on page1 image page 2 imageview get set and so on.

How set/reset current pages imageview?

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing getItemPosition method like this:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return mDataSource.indexOf(object);
}
```

This way you'll get the position of each item correctly

Comment: I am new to android, what is mDatasource ? and how to use it?

Comment: The collection of fragments you pass to your PagerAdapter

Comment: I am not using any fragment

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set viewpager.setOffsetLimit(totalnumberofpage);
where totalnumberofpage is the count of list

Second thing is make ViewHolder class

```
private class ViewHolder {
TextView textViewItem;}
```

and use it like this way:

```
@Override
```

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
ViewHolderItem viewHolder;


  // The convertView argument is essentially a "ScrapView" as described is Lucas post 
  // http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/
  // It will have a non-null value when ListView is asking you recycle the row layout. 
  // So, when convertView is not null, you should simply update its contents instead of inflating a new row    layout.

if(convertView==null){

    // inflate the layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

    // well set up the ViewHolder
    viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
    viewHolder.textViewItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);

    // store the holder with the view.
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

}else{
    // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
    // just use the viewHolder
    viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
}

// object item based on the position
ObjectItem objectItem = data[position];

// assign values if the object is not null
if(objectItem != null) {
    // get the TextView from the ViewHolder and then set the text (item name) and tag (item ID) values
    viewHolder.textViewItem.setText(objectItem.itemName);
    viewHolder.textViewItem.setTag(objectItem.itemId);
}

return convertView;}
```